# How to make a program appear on the desktop like conky?

Tags: command-line, conky

I would like to make a terminal program run and appear on the desktop in the same way that `conky` does ( or at least a similar).

The effect I want to accomplish: Basically `conky` but with a command prompt area instead.

Comment: What you want is called a Tiling window manager, and AwesomeWM is a prime example of it.

Comment: not quite what you're looking for, but running guake or yakuake might work quite well for similar purposes - they are drop down, 'quake' style terminals

Comment: Conky writes directly to the X root window. I don't know of a terminal emulator that does this. I would imagine correctly handling events and focus would be difficult, but this might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for!

http://m.lifehacker.com/294005/embed-a-terminal-in-the-desktop-with-compiz-fusion

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

just use tilda terminal emulator
set it to be transparent, position and size.
You'll have terminal just like conky.
[image]